# What does $b_i\mid b_{i+1}$ for integers $b_i?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

In the computational topology literature, the reduction algorithm for computing the Smith normal form of a boundary matrix uses the notation $b_j > 1 \: \text{ and }\: b_j\mid b_{j+1}$ in the context of the diagonal elements of the Smith matrix. Can anyone give me an idea for what it means?

Comment: The b_i are integers and | stands for "divides."

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks very much. That makes perfect sense. I assume this is standard notation, perhaps in algebra or number theory?

Comment: yes, it's standard notation in this context.

Answer (score 2):

> The $b_i$ are integers and $|$ stands for "divides."

-Qiaochu Yuan

> Yes, it's standard notation in this context.

-lhf

---

See also Wikipedia's ["List of mathematical symbols"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols) and ["Vertical bar."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics)